# Delphi Set of Enumeration

Tags: delphi, set, enumeration

I'm trying to filter my logging. If a log (or message) type is in the options, I want to send it to the log, otherwise exit.

The compilation fails on the "if not MessageType in..." line with:

`"[dcc32 Error] uMain.pas(2424): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type"`

I think it must be possible (and reasonably simple) based on the Include/Exclude functions, which I tried looking at but couldn't find anywhere (i.e. Include(MySet, llInfo); ).

My declaration are as follows:

```
type
  TLogLevel = (llDebug, llError, llWarn, llInfo, llException);
  TLogOptions = set of TLogLevel;

var
  FLogOptions: TLogOptions; 

procedure TfrmMain.Log(const s: String; MessageType: TLogLevel;
  DebugLevel: Integer; Filter: Boolean = True);
begin


  if not MessageType in FLogOptions then
    exit;

  mmoLog.Lines.Add(s);
end;
```

Comment: Apologies!! I should have added that the compilation fails on the "if not MessageType in..." line with:


[dcc32 Error] uMain.pas(2424): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

Comment: Copy that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need parentheses around the set operation because of operator precedence. The compiler is parsing it as `if not MessageType`, which is not a valid operation. If you put parentheses around the set test, the compiler can parse it correctly.

```
if not (MessageType in FLogOptions) then
```

This is a common issue, and is not specific to set types. For instance, you can get the same error with the following express as well.

```
if not 1 = 2 and 2 = 3 then
```

Adding parentheses around the two equality tests will correct the error.

```
if not (1 = 2) and (2 = 3) then
```

For more information, you can see the documentation for [Operator Precedence](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Operator_Precedence)

Comment: This is a very common mistake, indeed, especially the `=` case. But in that case it is arguably better to write `1 <> 2`.

Comment: I'd expect `not 1 = 2` to compile and evaluate to `False`

Comment: Yes, "the same error", is a bit misleading since the OP talks about the E2015 "Operator not applicable to this operand type" compile-time error. It might be a good idea to include a brief warning about bitwise negation in this A.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You're right. I gave a bad example. Edited.